# Adding the id during the installation of the android app

Tags: android

Hello please guide me about this query . i am making the android app , in which the user will give his personal no and after contacting with server , the app will show all avaliable services for him . we can say it as a user id . The thing  i am wondering about is that how we give the id during the installation of apk file . i mean to say when the user is installing the app it will ask for the personal no and for the rest of the time there is no need to give the personal no , and later on how easily i can fetch the id to query the records at server side .Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't ask anything during installation process. But you can ask user for his ID on first run of your app, and then just store it in `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: Thanks for your concern. Any idea or tutorial that can guide how it will execute for the first time and later on it should not .

Comment: The example is provided in `SteD's` answer.

Answer (score 2):

When the activity first launched, retrieve from the shared preferences:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("user",MODE_PRIVATE);
String userID = sharedPref.getString("ID","null");
```

If it is a first timer, userID will have a `null` value.

```
if(userID == null && userID.length() == 0){
 //Do a post to web server
 //Retrieve user ID created from web server and store it in shared preference
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("user",MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedPref.edit();
prefEditor.putString("userID", userIdFromWeb);
prefEditor.commit();
}
```

Comment: In `String userID = sharedPref.getString("ID","null");` -> `null` should be without quotes. 

`if(userID == null && userID.length() == 0){` -> should be `if(userID == null || userID.length() == 0){`.

`prefEditor.putString("userID", userIdFromWeb);` -> should be `"user"` instead of `"userID"`.`

Comment: putString is taking a pair of key and value, you can use basically use whatever name you want.

Comment: I've made a mistake either. :) The correction:
`prefEditor.putString("userID", userIdFromWeb);` -> should be `"ID"` instead of `"userID"`.

Comment: Thanks alot man . please correct me if i am wrong what  it will be doing like this that for the first time it will be taking the id from the user from SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("user",MODE_PRIVATE);
String userID = sharedPref.getString("ID","null"); and later on it will be fetching from the server so i have to store the id on the server for the comparison